Proof of Bekenstein bound
I am trying to find a student-friendly (but mathematically rigorous) proof of the Bekenstein bound. Unfortunately, all the proofs I have found are too complicated to understand (most of them refer to quantum field theory, which I am not very familiar with). So I just want to know if there is some "elementary" proof of this inequality? Or not elementary, but very consistent and detailed? I would be grateful for any links, especially educational literature, where this problem is considered in detail from scratch.

I don't think there is such a thing in elementary terms, it's more of an additional plausible idea which some people believe a quantum theory consistent with observed facts about gravity should obey. Bekenstein says he derived it from the requirement that 2nd law of thermodynamics is valid also when black holes affect processes, which is an extrapolation of 2nd law to situations it has never been tested in. Also, a satisfactory quantum theory consistent with facts about gravity is not known. Bekenstein's paper: http://old.phys.huji.ac.il/~bekenste/PRD23-287-1981.pdf


I am trying to find a student-friendly (but mathematically rigorous) proof of the Bekenstein bound.

This does not exist. In fact, one of the main arguments against the Bekenstein bound is that none of the quantities involved in the bound are sufficiently well-defined in order for it to make sense. The Bekenstein bound can only be proven in a very handwavy manner (by neglecting all the subtleties in the definitions of the quantities involved), or by giving precise definitions of everything and rendering the proof particularly more technical (usually involving Tomita–Takesaki modular theory). An excellent introduction to entropy bounds are the lectures by Raphael Bousso at the 2018 Arnold Sommerfeld School.
To give an example, let us start with Bekenstein's original result. He claims
$$S \leq 2 \pi E R,$$
where $S$ is the entropy content of some object, $E$ is its energy, and $R$ is the radius of the smallest sphere capable of containing the object. Now let us pick an example: a hydrogen atom. This immediately yields an issue. What is the size of a hydrogen atom? The wavefunction extends indefinitely, so should the atom be considered infinite? Alternatively, maybe we should just pick something at the scale of the Bohr radius, but then we are leaving out the possibility of the electron being even further away. Furthermore, if we pick a finite radius, then we get the issue that finite regions in space always have infinite entropy in quantum field theory, and thus the bound is broken. How come?
In 2008, Casini found a way of making the bound much more rigorous by employing methods coming from algebraic quantum field theory (namely, Tomita–Takesaki modular theory), see arXiv: 0804.2182. Shortly, Casini interprets the entropy as being the relative entropy (meaning the entropy of the quantum state minus the entropy of the vacuum, which yields a finite result once both quantities are regularized) and by interpreting the right-hand side of the bound in terms of the modular operator. In some scenarios, this modular operators resembles exactly the quantity Bekenstein originally wrote, but in most cases the modular operator lacks any direct interpretation.
To my knowledge, Casini's approach is what led to the most mathematically sound results concerning the Bekenstein bound. Nevertheless, it gives a very different presentation to the bound. I've even heard some researchers stating that it seems more fair to refer to it as the Casini bound than the Bekenstein bound.

I have recently heard about arXiv: 2409.14408 by Roberto Longo, but I haven't read it in detail yet. Perhaps it gives a more direct meaning to the Bekenstein bound, but I find it unlikely to be elementary (unless you consider functional analysis and operator algebras an elementary topic)
